# The quail did not perch in a tree, that wasn’t its way

Tags: idiom-requests, popular-refrains, proverb-requests

This is a Georgian idiomatic expression. It conveys the idea that, as a quail will never perch in a tree because it can not, so a person will not be able to accomplish a task or perform, due to his/her inability. Under the word **inability**, I mean both - mental and physical ineptitude. Is there an equivalent expression with the similar meaning in English ?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with it the way it's stated.

Answer (score 2):

I can think of a couple of expressions that are similar to, if not the same as, your expression. One is "[like a fish out of water](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+fish+out+of+water)"; the other is "[out of one's element](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/be+out+of+element)".

To novelist Robert Heinlein is attributed "[Never attempt to teach a pig to sing; it wastes your time and annoys the pig.](https://quoteinvestigator.com/2017/07/10/sing-pig/)"

Answer (score 0):

> We can't all play first violin in the orchestra, [somebody has to push
>   wind through the trombone.]

{[Pressreader.com](https://www.pressreader.com/south-africa/saturday-star/20090919/281960308794006)}

I'm quite familiar with this expression (I've even heard someone invert it to give the reverse meaning). I'm very surprised that there are so few hits on the internet.